# In flutter and dart is param without type is slower?

Tags: flutter, dart

Which is faster? with or without the types.

Design 1

```
home: Builder(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Home();
  }
)
```

Design 2

```
home: Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    return Home();
  }
)
```

Comment: I don't think one's faster than the other

Comment: In your example, there would be no difference since the type will be inferred.  However, for cases where no type can be inferred, then the type will end up being `dynamic`, and there will be a runtime penalty.

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly the same at run time.

Dart uses type inference for method arguments. So even if you don't specify it in your "Design 2", the compiler knows that the `context` argument is of type `BuildContext`, based one the declaration of the `Builder` constructor.